# How to export environment variable from Jenkins Build Flow Plugin?

Tags: jenkins

From the called build flow job, I've tried both:

```
build.environment['AOEU'] = 'aoeu' // callee would `println called.environment['AOEU']`
```

and:

```
upstream.environment['AOEU'] = 'aoeu' // callee would `println build.environment['AOEU']`
```

with no luck.

Comment: I think in the Build Flow script, you use `build.environment.get('AOEU')`. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @DaveBacher, there are two build flow jobs. I want to export an environment variable from one to another. It occurred to me that since the job runs on master, this isn't possible. I'm going to try using the file system to pass information from one job to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fought a lot with that too and found no clean way to do it. I finally used `EnvInjectPlugin` in some ugly way to do this.

```
def buildEnv = build.getEnvVars();
varsToAdd =  [:] 
  // add here your custom properties
buildEnv.putAll(varsToAdd) 
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectPluginAction
def envInjectAction = build.getAction(EnvInjectPluginAction.class);
envInjectAction.overrideAll(buildEnv)
```

... the EnvInject plugin did the magic

I first tried to implement [EnvironmentContributingAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/EnvironmentContributingAction.html)
 and add it as `build.addAction(...)` but did not work for me for unknown reason.

Be sure to set 'Flow run needs a workspace' in the called job.

Comment: When I try that, it emits the error: `Script1.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectPluginAction`

Comment: Do you have [EnvInjectPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) installed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we do. We definitely have a plugin installed that injects env vars.

Answer (score 2):

@NoelYap: I can't comment on Hristo's answer, but it's the correct answer. The missing detail is that importing EnvInject only works if your job has the 'Flow run needs a workspace' option selected.

Comment: I can't, my reputation is not high enough.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version based on Michael's solution

```
import hudson.model.*

def setEnvVariable(final String key, final String value) {
    Thread.currentThread().getCurrentExecutable()
        .addAction(new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue(key, value))
    );
}

setEnvVariable("THIS_ENV_VAR", "Hello World")
```

The variable is then available in the post-build actions.

Answer (score 0):

An old question I know, but this is how i get around it. The beautiful part is this code works well in Jenkins both within the system evaluated groovy and within the Build FLow Job DSL.

Just drop the import statements when running it from the System Groovy job/console as they are already available.

As a bonus this class also helps get the environment variable regardless of the Groovy context. Still in the build flow you should favor `build.environment.get` it is more natural.

Note: 'Flow run needs a workspace' should be checked.

```
//Import the required bindings for a Build Flow DSL
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild
import hudson.model.EnvironmentContributingAction
import hudson.EnvVars
//Drop the above if running with a System Groovy Console/Job

class Job {
  static def getVariable(String key) {
    def config = new HashMap()
    def thr = Thread.currentThread()
    def build = thr?.getCurrentExecutable()
    def envVarsMap = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("envVars")
    config.putAll(envVarsMap)
    return config.get(key)
  }
  static def setVariable(String key, String value) {
    def build = Thread.currentThread().getCurrentExecutable()
    def action = new VariableInjectionAction(key, value)
    build.addAction(action)
    build.getEnvironment()
  }
  static def setVariable(String key, Integer value) {
    setVariable(key, value.toString())
  }
}
class VariableInjectionAction implements EnvironmentContributingAction {
  private String key
  private String value
  public VariableInjectionAction(String key, String value) {
    this.key = key
    this.value = value
  }
  public void buildEnvVars(AbstractBuild build, EnvVars envVars) {
    if (envVars != null && key != null && value != null) {
      envVars.put(key, value);
    }
  }
  public String getDisplayName()  { return "VariableInjectionAction"; }
  public String getIconFileName() { return null; }
  public String getUrlName()      { return null; }
}

Job.setVariable("THIS_ENV_VAR", "Hello World")
```

Will set the environment variable THIS_ENV_VAR to "Hello World"