# Get Build Number from another job in Jenkins as a variable

Tags: jenkins

I am running a Build Flow job that executes multiple builds in parallel and then use the Post-build Action to Publish HTML reports.

How can I get the build number of each of the individual jobs as a variable so I can use when fetching the HTML report?

***EDIT***

This is what my parallel code looks like:

```
parallel (
  { uarr = build("Baseline - Secure - UARR", param1: build.properties.get("number")) },
  { login = build("Baseline - Secure - Login", param2: build.properties.get("number")) }
)
```

And this is what i tried using when using the Publish HTML reports for the Index page[s], but it's not seeing ${param1} as a variable and trying to find it literally:

```
*Secure Baseline*Secure_UARR-${param1}.html
```

This is what I'm using in the Maven build job and it is working great at finding the report with the correct filename that contains the build number:

```
*Secure Baseline*Secure_UARR-${BUILD_NUMBER}.html
```

The problem is, if I use that same logic in the Build Flow parallel job, it uses the build number of that job, not the Maven job that creates the report. (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: def n = build("JOB_NAME", PARAM_1: "value-1", PARAM_2: true, ...)

Comment: But how do I then use those params in the Post-build Action?

Comment: Aha, that's what you are looking for. I think if you want that you will have to make them environment variables

Comment: Ya, that's what I'm trying to figure out how to do right now. I have added my code to my question.

Comment: Updated the answer with a snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can store the job references in a variable

```
parallel(
 job1: { def n = build("JOB_NAME", PARAM_1: "value-1", PARAM_2: true, ...) }
...
)
```

or even store them in an array if you like

```
def jobs = [:]

parallel(
    job1: { 
      def n1 = build("job1", param1: "value1", ...) 
      jobs["job1"] = n1.number
    },
    job1: { 
      def n2 = build("job2", param1: "value1", ...) 
      jobs["job2"] = n2.number
    },
    job1: { 
      def n3 = build("job3", param1: "value1", ...) 
      jobs["job3"] = n3.number
    },
    jobm: { 
      def nm = build("jobm", param1: "value1", ...) 
      jobs["jobm"] = n1.number
    }
)
```

And then you can read the map when you want

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029589/how-to-export-environment-variable-from-jenkins-build-flow-plugin#answer-31165740) shows how to export this as environment variables.

```
def buildEnv = build.getEnvVars();
buildEnv.putAll(jobs) 
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectPluginAction
def envInjectAction = build.getAction(EnvInjectPluginAction.class);
envInjectAction.overrideAll(buildEnv)
```

You can the use it in your postbuild step(s) as `$job1`, `$job2`, ..., `$jobm`.

This [resolved bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10273) suggests that you then can use it in the [HTML-publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) (I am not verry familiar with the plugin)

Comment: The source also sort of suggests it (did not trace it back entirely) https://github.com/jenkinsci/htmlpublisher-plugin/blob/cc21888701a965e5a47b23dbf57d55825166de17/src/main/java/htmlpublisher/HtmlPublisher.java#L150